# Naming of an image when building it does not work

Tags: image, docker

My goal is to name an image when building it from a Dockerfile. However, for a particular image (based on a corporate template I have to use) `-t myImage` seems to have no effect.

What do I mean by that? If I run `docker build -t myImage .` and then `docker images` both the repository and the tag column are empty. Here is a screenshot with said image in the second row.

[image]

The first row shows a test image I built with `docker build -t test .` based on this Dockerfile:

```
FROM busybox
RUN echo "hello world"
```

Naming the said image after it has been built with `docker tag 1cb myImage` works.

Comment: Show the full command line you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following command in your project directory :

```
docker build -t=myImage .
```

or

```
docker build --tag=myImage .
```

This should work!

Comment: This worked! But how come that I do not need the '=' for naming the BusyBox image?

Comment: In your case it seems that you are building an image from busybox, which means you are using this image as a parent image. So when you build your dockerfile it will automatically pull the image of busybox from the docker hub. So that's why you don't have to worry about the naming of the parent image or any image you are pulling from the dockerhub. You can also choose the tag of the image that you are pulling (different version of the image)